# Need to understand : ping

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, ping

I am using ubuntu 13.10 and 
I have used ping before to check server is up/down.

Can someone help me understand, as I'm unable to find anything explaining this
I did the usual ping command

```
ping 8.8.8.8
```

output without google domain

```
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=48 time=35.9 ms
```

**Please note the trailing .(period) in IP**

```
ping 8.8.8.8.
```

output with google domain

```
64 bytes from google-public-dns-a.google.com (8.8.8.8): icmp_seq=1 ttl=48 time=35.3 ms
```

**Output:**

```
developer@chnphp006:~$ ping 8.8.8.8

PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=48 time=35.9 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=48 time=35.7 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=48 time=46.2 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=4 ttl=48 time=36.6 ms
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3005ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 35.779/38.658/46.276/4.415 ms


developer@chnphp006:~$ ping 8.8.8.8.

PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from google-public-dns-a.google.com (8.8.8.8): icmp_seq=1 ttl=48 time=35.3 ms
64 bytes from google-public-dns-a.google.com (8.8.8.8): icmp_seq=2 ttl=48 time=35.1 ms
64 bytes from google-public-dns-a.google.com (8.8.8.8): icmp_seq=3 ttl=48 time=36.1 ms
64 bytes from google-public-dns-a.google.com (8.8.8.8): icmp_seq=4 ttl=48 time=35.8 ms
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 35.128/35.631/36.145/0.441 ms
```

What difference does the trailing period make in ping command?

Update:

This happens only on **Ubuntu** systems, not in centos/Debian.

Other Ex:

```
developer@chnphp006:~$ ping 198.252.206.16
PING 198.252.206.16 (198.252.206.16) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 198.252.206.16: icmp_seq=1 ttl=52 time=258 ms
64 bytes from 198.252.206.16: icmp_seq=2 ttl=52 time=258 ms
64 bytes from 198.252.206.16: icmp_seq=3 ttl=52 time=273 ms
^C
--- 198.252.206.16 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2000ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 258.144/263.339/273.598/7.278 ms

developer@chnphp006:~$ ping 198.252.206.16.
PING 198.252.206.16 (198.252.206.16) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from stackoverflow.com (198.252.206.16): icmp_seq=1 ttl=52 time=259 ms
64 bytes from stackoverflow.com (198.252.206.16): icmp_seq=2 ttl=52 time=267 ms
64 bytes from stackoverflow.com (198.252.206.16): icmp_seq=3 ttl=52 time=271 ms
^C
--- 198.252.206.16 ping statistics ---
7 packets transmitted, 6 received, 14% packet loss, time 6000ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 258.292/264.777/274.093/6.447 ms
```

Comment: could have explained while down vote!..either what is wrong in my question or the how this happening!..
otherwise, What is the meaning of down vote?

Comment: This happens only in ubuntu system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically a trailing dot is used to denote that the hostname used is a fully qualified domainname (under the DNS root).

Appending the dot would prevent the search-domain from being appended to (short) hostnames in DNS lookups. Why it has the result it does in your examples with an **IP-address**, I don't know.

It may be that normally a hostname with a dot <kbd>.</kbd> also gets interpreted as a FQDN except when the decimal representation of an IP-address( four numbers [0-255] separated by dots) is detected, but that matching rule fails when the trailing dot is added to the ip-address.

If your search domain is `example.com` and the A record for `www.example.com.` exists:

```
ping www
```

should resolve to :

```
ping www.example.com.
```

and the A record of your webserver and result in some ICMP packets being sent to your webserver.

```
ping www.
```

will fail, because AFAIK there is no top-level domain `www`

Answer (score 3):

The trailing period changes it from an IP address that it just uses in numeric form to a domain name that it looks up using reverse address resolution (in-addr.arpa domain).